# Corda Letter of Credit demo is not working

Tags: corda

I have cloned the [Letter of Credit Demo](https://github.com/corda/LetterOfCredit) of Corda. I created and ran the node driver. All nodes were up and running without any errors as per the console. But when I try to Start the demo with http://localhost:10014/web/loc/, the demo is not getting started. I just get the below error

> HTTP ERROR 404 Problem accessing /web/loc/. Reason: Not Found

Can someone assist me in knowing what I am missing here. Should I need to explicitly clone the front end and do something?

Answer (score 0):

The LetterofCreditWeb part has to be completed.